# Best practice for declaring variable without initialising it, so auto is unavailable

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to declare two variables of the same type, and have the compiler figure out the types.  However I don't want to initialise one of the variables until later.  I don't think I can use `auto` here, so what's the best option?

```
std::vector<int> v;

// `start` and `end` should be the same type
auto start = v.begin();
??? end;

// complicated code to assign a value to `end` (i.e. putting
// the code in a function or using ?: is not practical here)  
if (...) {
    end = ...;
} else {
    end = v.end();
}
```

What's the best way to tell the compiler that `end` should be the same type as `start`, but without having to initialise the variable?

```
auto start = v.begin(), end;  // Doesn't work, `end` has to be initialised
decltype(start) end;          // Does work, but not sure if it's best practice
```

**Update**

A couple of comments have suggested ways that would work in certain situations, so I am clarifying my situation here:

```
std::vector<int> v;
int amount = 123;

// `start` and `end` should be the same type
auto start = v.begin();
??? end;

// code to assign a value to `end`
if (amount) {
    end = start + amount;
    amount = 0;
} else {
    end = v.end();
}
```

I believe a lambda function would be trickier here, because `amount` is being reset to `0` after `end` is calculated, so in a lambda function that calculates a value for `end`, `amount = 0` would have to come after the `return` statement.  The only option would be to create more local variables, which would incur an (admittedly tiny) performance penalty.

Comment: I'd use `decltype`.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking :-)  Maybe there's a better way I'm not aware of!  I haven't seen any examples using `decltype` to declare local variables so it made me wonder.

Comment: If the type you're working with is a class type that is not default-constructable then `decltype` alone is a non-starter; in that case consider using `decltype` + [`boost::optional<>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/).

Comment: Another option, of course, would be to re-write your logic using the ternary operator or a lambda function (with deduced return type).  This would also have the advantage that you don't leave uninitialized variables lying around and you won't have the issue mentioned by @ildjarn.

Comment: If I understand it correctly though, I'd then have to "capture" a dozen or so variables into the lambda function?  That's a very verbose solution!

Comment: @Malvineous : `[&]` is not verbose. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: Just found that, that's acceptable :-)  Unfortunately my original code sets `end` and then changes variables used to calculate `end`, so in order for this to work as a lambda function I would either have to run code after the `return` or create new local variables, so I'm not sure if this is the best solution in this particular case.

Comment: @Malvineous : If those variables are created before the lambda then they will be capured as well; your problem isn't clear to me.

Comment: @ildjarn: I have added an update to the question to explain what I mean.  The presence of `amount = 0` after it was used to calculate `end` is what I believe will cause problems with the lambda function (or require more variables to be introduced.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My personal approach would be to call a lambda in-place:

```
std::vector<int> v;

///////////////////

auto start = v.begin(), end = [&]{
    if (...) {
        // complicated code to compute a value for `end`
    }
    else
        return v.end();
}();
```

If automatic return type deduction for the lambda fails for any reason (e.g. there are multiple `return` statements), just replace `[&]{` with `[&]() -> decltype(start) {`.

---

**Edit:**

```
std::vector<int> v;
int amount = 123;

///////////////////

auto start = v.begin(), end = [&]{
    auto ret = v.end();
    if (amount) {
        ret = start + amount;
        amount = 0;
    }
    return ret;
}();
```

Comment: What's the performance impact of the `auto ret` line?  Does it allocate a more memory (and then get copied in the `return` statement), or does it get optimised out because of its use as a return value?

Comment: @Malvineous : With optimizations enabled, [NRVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) will eliminate it on any compiler supporting C++11. In any case, an iterator is about as cheap as it gets to move/copy if need be. ;-]

Comment: Fair point :-)  In this case I think this solution will work after all - many thanks!

Comment: I'd expect a good compiler to be able to optimize away the whole lambda in this case and produce identical code as if you had declared an uninitialized variable with the correct type and conditionally initialized it in-place.

Comment: @5gon12eder : Indeed, I think the lambda would have to be truly massive to not get inlined, especially since the lambda itself isn't persisted.

Comment: IIFE is virtually guaranteed to be the fastest option, reddit users vetted that recently http://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/2q1p7x/complex_object_initialization_optimization_with/

Answer (score 9):

I think an uninitialized variable here is premature optimization. I would initialize the variable and only consider optimizing if I have evidence that it would have an impact.

```
auto start = v.begin();
auto end = v.end();

if (amount) {
    end = start + amount;
    amount = 0;
}
```

Comment: I agree (and upvoted), but the OP did comment that he needs to capture 'a dozen or so' variables while we only see two, so it's hard to say how oversimplified the code in the question is vs. the OP's real code.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example using the good old ternary operator (also mentioned by  @5gon12eder). In such a simple case it's way the best comprehensible IMHO, and also avoids the problems of uninitialized variables, pointed out by @ildjarn.

```
auto start = v.begin();
auto end = amount
    ? start + amount
    : v.end();
amount = 0;
```

Comment: As mentioned in my original question, the actual code includes many statements for each condition, so using the ternary operator makes it pretty unreadable.  But this is a fair point if the code is actually as simple as my simplified example is!

Answer (score 5):

```
auto start = v.begin();
decltype(start) end; // Must have a default constructor though.
```

Comment: Isn't this basically a copy & paste from the OP?  I'd appreciate it if you could add some explanation why you think that this is a better solution than the OP (who apparently is already aware of it) thinks.

Answer (score 5):

Is it not *overthinking* the problem? Either go for your first intuition:

```
auto start = v.begin();
decltype(start) end;
```

Or `auto`-initialize the `end` variable with `v.end()`, and drop the `else` clause in your demonstration code. It's as simple as that:

```
auto start = v.begin();
auto end = v.end(); // Or v.begin() depending on your preference, the whole container or nothing by default

// code to assign a value to `end` IF it must be different from v.end()
if (amount) {
    end = start + amount;
    amount = 0;
}
```

The cost of initializing or assigning an iterator should be negligible anyway, compared to the maintenance/readability cost.

Comment: That's true, but only for this specific case.  There are other situations (for me) where there are no iterators and the assignments are all expensive, so I was asking for the general case, only using iterators here as a simple example.

Comment: Then use `decltype()` and be sure your type is [trivially constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible). If not, make it so, with a constructor taking a [type_tag](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching) for example (i.e. `nullptr_t` or something of your own).